# How to `remove_action` from plugin

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'm using a third-party plugin that has an function hooked to the `plugins_loaded` hook. From the plugin file itself:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'acf_qtranslate_monkey_patch', 3);
```

This is *not* in a class. This function is causing a few PHP notices, so I wanted to remove the action, but it's failing to. I've tried this in my `functions.php`:

```
function my_remove_action() {
    remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'acf_qtranslate_monkey_patch', 3);
}
add_action('setup_theme','my_remove_action'); // This action happens *after* plugins_loaded
```

I've also tried hooking it to `plugins_loaded` as well and just putting it straight into functions without hooking it to any action, but neither worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to not hook in any action, just using `remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'acf_qtranslate_monkey_patch', 3);` in your fundtions.php file?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well. I've edited the question above to clarify.

Comment: try adding `priority` to your `add_action` as 4th.

Comment: `add_action('plugins_loaded','my_remove_action', 4);`

Comment: @ShyamMakwana.me Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for but..
Just comment out the plugin function "acf_qtranslate_monkey_patch".
It's not compatible with ACF 5, but will be once updated (is my guess)
So when you update it, it wont be a problem no more.

Comment: @Jeppe I always avoid editing other people's plugins as it messes up the ability to cleanly update the plugin in the future, hence my need to simply remove the action. It's not actually an issue with ACF either; the function patches an issue with qTranslate. Thanks for your input though!